# Add even numbered lines to odd numbered lines; keep even numbered lines as is

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to use awk or sed to add the text from all even numbered lines to the ends of all odd numbered lines while keeping the even numbered lines as is.

For example, I have:

```
>1
AAAA
>2
BBBB
>3
CCCC
```

and I need a new file that looks like this:

```
>1:AAAA
AAAA
>2:BBBB
BBBB
>3:CCCC
CCCC
```

The colon is arbitrary but would work just fine for what I need.  The files are huge (~ 3,000,000,000 lines!) so it needs to be fast.  Not sure if awk or sed would be better and how to do it.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat sample.csv                                                                                                                                                                    
>1
AAAA
>2
BBBB
>3
CCCC
```

Below is the awk script:
If it is an odd line, store the value into an array, when encounters the next even line, print the formatted line

```
cat test.awk                                                                                                                                                                      
{
    if(NR %2 != 0){
        a[NR] = $0
    }else{
        print a[NR -1] ":" $0 "\n" $0
    }
}
```

Run it and display result:

```
awk -f test.awk  sample.csv                                                                                                                                                       
>1:AAAA
AAAA
>2:BBBB
BBBB
>3:CCCC
CCCC
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v OFS=: '!(NR%2){print p OFS $0; print} {p=$0}' file

>1:AAAA
AAAA
>2:BBBB
BBBB
>3:CCCC
CCCC
```

set OFS to the desired delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;s/\n(.*)/:\1&/' file
```

Append odd lines to the even lines and using pattern matching format the output.

Comment: Well done. I like the use of both back reference methods, I usually separate one style or the other.